# Program's old processes stay when ftp is offline

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, file-upload, timer, ftp

I have a program that restarts itself once in a while. The program uses a timer which starts a thread that uploads files from a folder to my ftp server. But when the ftp server goes down, the program still restarts itself as needed, but the old process doesn't close and stays in Task Manager. When the ftp comes back up, it starts to end the processes.

This problem doesn't occur when the ftp server is online.

What could be causing the processes to stay when the ftp server is offline?

To restart the program i just use `Application.Restart()`

Current code:

```
Public Sub UploadToFTP()
    Dim request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(FtpAdress), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
    Try
        Using response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
            Try
                Dim _FromPath As String
                Dim _ToPath As String
                Dim Dt As New DataTable
                Dim flag As Boolean = False

                'Create a link to an FtpServer
                Dim ftp As New FTPclient(_HostName, _UserName, _Password)
                Dim _dir As New DirectoryInfo(sourceDir)
                ' Upload multiple files
                For Each _file As FileInfo In _dir.GetFiles("*.*")
                    _FromPath = sourceTxt + _file.Name
                    _ToPath = "/UploadedData /" + _file.Name
                    'upload a file
                    flag = ftp.Upload(_FromPath, _ToPath)
                    '' file uploaded then delete
                    If flag Then
                        _file.Delete()
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Using
    Catch ex As WebException
        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(ex.Response, FtpWebResponse)
        'Does not exist
        If response.StatusCode = FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable Then
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    FTPup = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf UploadToFTP)
    FTPup.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
    FTPup.Start()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FTPup.IsBackground = True` this makes the thread belong to the app and should close it the app closes.

Comment: Thank you, it works.
It now closes the old process after a few seconds.